# flutter direct share to whatsapp and telegram in android and ios

Tags: android, flutter, dart, share, whatsapp

I want share a pdf file from flutter, directly to whatsapp and telegram in ios and android

Note 1: Flutter [share_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus) package can't do this, I want directly share to whatsapp and telegram without device native appchooser dialog for share.

Note 2: I don't want use universal links, because I can't sent file with this method, universal links only supports text.

Is there any package for this purpose?
If there isn't, How can I write native code for this in ios and android?

Answer (score -1):

Use this plugin to share all social media platforms [socioal_share](https://pub.dev/packages/social_share)

Or if want to use this plugin for whatsapp, use the [whatsapp_share: ^1.1.1](https://pub.dev/packages/whatsapp_share) plugin

```
import 'package:whatsapp_share/whatsapp_share.dart';
```

**For text**

```
Future<void> share() async {
    await WhatsappShare.share(
      text: 'Whatsapp share text',
      linkUrl: 'https://flutter.dev/',
      phone: '911234567890',
    );
  }
```

**For Files**

```
Future<void> shareFile() async {
    await WhatsappShare.shareFile(
      text: 'Whatsapp share text',
      phone: '911234567890',
      filePath: [_image1.path, _image2.path],
    );
  }
```

Comment: whatsapp_share package isn't null safety and phone is require, I don't access to user contacts in my app and social_share isn't support files

Comment: ok bro @amir_a14